# Кнопки "Вам понравилась статья - ДА - НЕТ"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, cookie

Суть такая нужны кнопки ДА и НЕТ в конце статьи отвечающие на вопрос Понравилась ли статья.

1. При нажатии на кнопке ответ через AJAX сохраняется в БД в конкретной
   статье. В админке можно посмотреть сколько ДА и сколько НЕТ
2. Для исключения многократного нажатия (накручивания счетчика) реализована индетефикация пользователя по IP.

   2.1. создана таблица в БД с тремя столбцами (user_ip, post_id и result)

   2.2. При заходе пользователя мы проверяем совпадает ли реальный IP пользователя и ID поста именно парой с тем что есть в БД если находим эту пару то закрашиваем кнопку того ответа который дал пользователь, но он может поменять свой ответ т.е. вторая кнопка не закрашена и кликабельна. Если не находим нужную пару то записываем данные в нашу таблицу в БД

Все работает нормально, есть только одно НО. IP пользователя величина очень не постоянная и может часто меняться особенно на мобильных как минимум при каждом подключении новый IP, бывает и чаще.

**Отсюда вопрос как повысить точность определения (индетефикации) пользователя?**

А иначе получается что один и тот же человек может довольно часто голосовать за одно и тоже просто меняя IP. Понятно что большинство специально так делать не будут, но даже не специально, возможно что человек заходит три дня подряд с мобильного с разных IP и и видит как будто он не голосовал и повторно голосует в надежде что его голос учтется, но он уже третий раз голосует.

Answer (score 3):

Повысить точность можно путём установки куки или записи в localStorage. Но это сработает при условии, что пользователь заходит с одного и того же устройства/браузера.

А вообще единственный способ избежать повторного голосования - это регистрация и аутентификация пользователя. Других вариантов нет - всё остальное можно при желании легко обойти.

Comment: это понятно что самое надежное это регистрация, но в данном случае это не приемлемо, т.к. кнопки нужны для определения качества материала и анализа, а обязательная регистрация в данном случае снизит вероятность нажатия кнопки просто в разы

Comment: Про куки я думал, сейчас рабочий вариант который я обдумываю это двойная проверка по куки и ip

Comment: @user242682 Думайте о целесообразности. Никому не сдалось накручивать кнопки под вашими статьями. Поэтому нет никакого смысла изобретать сложную системы защиты. Кука + ip, этого достаточно.